# React Native: How to display contents on next line rather than going off View

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am building a react native application and am trying to render a number of boxes in a line. The problem is, the number of boxes rendered can vary depending on different circumstances, and thus there are cases where the the number of boxes is too great and thus go past the end of the View they are being rendered in (Boxes dont wrap to next line in the view, which I want them to). The code I am using to do this can be seen below:

```
<View style={{height: '100%', width:'100%', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>
                        {props.boxes.map((element, index) => {
                            return (
                                <View key={index} style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                                    <Box color={color}/>
                                    <Text>Some Text Here</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        })}
</View>
```

What property can I add to make the boxes wrap around to the next line of the View when they reach the edge of the View? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
```

OR

`flexShrink: 1` instead of `flex:1`.

> This is already a bug and using any of these above answers should solver your issue. try playing around `width` size.

```html
<Text style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}> Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here
   </Text>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! When I changed the width to`80%` is started working.

Comment: Correct, if you see in the answer I also mentioned about playing around the width size, which is what happens often, Glad it worked.